# Attach pdf to only specific email notification in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, email-notifications

Attach pdf to **ONLY** woocomerce new order email

I am using this code but the PDF gets attched to every email in woocommerce

```
 add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_attachments', 'attach_terms_conditions_pdf_to_email', 10, 3);
 function attach_terms_conditions_pdf_to_email ( $attachments , $email_id, $email_object ) {

     $your_pdf_path = get_template_directory() . '/terms123.pdf';
    $attachments[] = $your_pdf_path;

    return $attachments;
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update 2**

> **There is no "New order" notification for customers** in Woocommerce… Depending on the payment methods enabled, the notifications to target can be "Customer On Hold Order" or/and Customer Processing Order" *(see the section at the end)*

The following will enable PDF attachment for Customer On Hold Order email notification:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_attachments', 'attach_terms_conditions_pdf_to_email', 10, 3 );
function attach_terms_conditions_pdf_to_email ( $attachments , $email_id, $email_object ) {
    // Avoiding errors and problems
    if ( ! is_a( $order, 'WC_Order' ) || ! isset( $email_id ) ) {
        return $attachments;
    }

    // Only for "Customer On Hold" email notification (for customer)
    if( $email_id === 'customer_on_hold_order' ){

        $your_pdf_path = get_template_directory() . '/terms123.pdf';
        $attachments[] = $your_pdf_path;
    }

    return $attachments;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme). Tested and works.

---

Depending on your enabled payment gateways in your installation, you can:

1) **You can use "Processing" emails instead,** replacing this line:

```
if( $email_id === 'customer_on_hold_order' ){
```

by this:

```
if( $email_id === 'customer_processing_order' ){
```

2) **You can use Both Customer "On Hold" and "Processing" emails,** replacing this line:

```
if( $email_id === 'customer_on_hold_order' ){
```

by this:

```
if( in_array( $email_id, array( 'customer_on_hold_order', 'customer_processing_order' ) ){
```

Comment: I want it for customer and not admin

Comment: @Sonia I have updated my answer, with some explanations…

Comment: For some reason it doesnt work for me. Where did you upload PDF document? @LoicTheAztec

Comment: @Wed on a child theme folder, you should use: `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` instead (for the path). See this related recent answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56288324/add-a-pdf-attachment-to-woocommerce-completed-order-email-notification/56289590#56289590

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I'm doing that. This is my code:

add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_attachments', 'attach_terms_conditions_pdf_to_email', 10, 3 );
function attach_terms_conditions_pdf_to_email ( $attachments , $email_id, $email_object ) {
    // Avoiding errors and problems
    if ( ! is_a( $order, 'WC_Order' ) || ! isset( $email_id ) ) {
        return $attachments;
    }

    if( $email_id === 'customer_on_hold_order' ){
        $attachments[] = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/terms.pdf';
    }
    return $attachments;
}

Comment: Question for LoicTheAztec. I used your code and had to change this line if ( $email_id === 'customer_on_hold_order' ){ to this one if( $email_id === array('customer_on_hold_order','customer_processing_order','customer_completed_order')){ Nothing happens, I am not getting any attachments to those mails. I could save the functions.php with this line `$email_id, array` because I was getting error about that comma ( , )

Comment: If I use it in a plugin what dir should I use

Comment: @LoicTheAztec is this only for the Woocommerce Invoice and Packaging Slip Plugin or can it be used without it?

Comment: @NordicGuy This thread is not related to any pdf plugin. Happy Christmas!