# Add a pdf attachment to WooCommerce completed order email notification

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, attachment, email-notifications

Found this code on another thread but can't make it work.
PDF uploaded to wp-content/child-theme/.

Goal is to attach the pdf to the completed order emails that woocommerce will send out.

Not sure if `customer_completed_order` is correct?

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_attachments', 'attach_terms_conditions_pdf_to_email', 10, 3 );
function attach_terms_conditions_pdf_to_email ( $attachments , $email_id, $email_object ) {
    // Avoiding errors and problems
    if ( ! is_a( $order, 'WC_Order' ) || ! isset( $email_id ) ) {
        return $attachments;
    }


    if( $email_id === 'customer_completed_order' ){

        $your_pdf_path = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/Q-0319B.pdf';
        $attachments[] = $your_pdf_path;
    }

    return $attachments;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

There are some errors in your code: The `$email_object` function argument is the wrong variable name and should be instead `$order` to match with your first if statement.

Now for the attachement path linked to the theme, you will use:

- `get_stylesheet_directory()` for a child theme
- `get_template_directory()` for a parent theme *(Website without a child theme)*

The email Id `customer_completed_order` is correct to target Customer "completed" email notification.

As you are not using the `$order` variable argument in your code, `! is_a( $order, 'WC_Order' )` is not needed, so the working code will be:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_attachments', 'attach_pdf_file_to_customer_completed_email', 10, 3);
function attach_pdf_file_to_customer_completed_email( $attachments, $email_id, $order ) {
    if( isset( $email_id ) && $email_id === 'customer_completed_order' ){
        $attachments[] = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/Q-0319B.pdf'; // Child theme
    }
    return $attachments;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and work.

---

For a parent theme replace:

```
$attachments[] = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/Q-0319B.pdf'; // Child theme
```

by the following line:

```
$attachments[] = get_template_directory() . '/Q-0319B.pdf'; // Parent theme
```

Comment: Thank you so much! :) Works like a charm now and I learned something aswell, perfect friday :)